Garage Door Remote Issue
I have two garage doors. Both Overhead Door Model 4050A. One has a frequency of 360 (Door A), and the second a frequency of 312 (Door B). They are both located in the same garage.
Currently, for (A) I've been using a single button Overhead Door brand remote to open the door. For (B) I've been using a SkyLink 3 Button MK-318-3 remote with a SkyLink GB-318 receiver crimped onto the line. Each remote controls their own door but not the other.
I now want two remotes of the same brand controlling both doors. So, I purchased two of the Genie Universal Series GU4TG-R.
Using the drop switches in (A) I was able to program the Genie remote. Then linking the SkyLink GB-318 on (B) I was able to also program the same Genie remote.
But here's the issue. The new Genie remote has a good range and can be operated from the driveway on (A) but it will not operate from the driveway on (B). It will open (B) from inside the garage but only when nearby.
I found this strange since the remote paired with the GB-318 fine and works. Additionally, the SkyLink MK-318-3 remote works from the driveway.
I don't know why the new Genie remote works fine on (A) but not on (B) when the remote seems to be working properly and other remotes can access the GB-318 receiver from a normal distance.
Anyways, any help would be great! Thanks!

MK-318-3 Remote
GB-318 Receiver
Genie Universal Remote
Instructions I used for pairing the two doors. Worked fine using alternative methods for each door


Do you happen to have LED lightbulbs near your opener?  Many brands of LED bulbs can cause interference with garage door openers, so that may be something to check.  There are LED bulbs that supposedly are compatible with garage door opener frequencies.  Not saying this is what's happening, but something to consider.  (note that they only cause interference when turned on, so if this is the case, the issue could appear to be intermittent, depending on if the bulbs are lit or not).

Hey, thanks! So, checked out the idea. There is a lightbulb attached to the opener. However, this issue persists whether or not the light is on or off. For example, the door still won't open when using the new remote from the driveway, even when the lightbulb is off.
